# Excluding non-imported users from people search SP2010

Tags: user-profile-service, people-search

The user profile service connection filter excludes any user accounts that don't have a custom 'user ID' attribute populated.

```
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $ups -GetNonImportedObjects $true
```

returns several users without user IDs.

I'm not sure how these users are getting into ups but this means that they can be found in the people search.

I've tried creating a new managed property for the user ID but I don't seem to be able to create a scope rule to require a wildcard ID or exclude blank IDs.

Is there another way to exclude them from search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this using the 'Append text to query' property of the 'People search core results' web part which allows a bit more flexibility than a scope rule.

Answer (score 1):

You could add additional query criteria to the People Result Source that includes your custom managed property.

The user profiles are being created when the users access the system. You may want to create a security group that prevents them from accessing SharePoint.

Comment: I've tried adding a scope rule with a property query but can't find a working syntax to either include userID = * or exclude userID = null. I'd prefer to allow users without an ID access to the system if at all possible.

Comment: Try a crawl rule with that logic against sps3://*

Answer (score 0):

Do an exclusion with "YourIdProperty>0"

Comment: unfortunately I can only use the equals operator for a property query, the example provided is Author = John Doe